# filter element from the list python, how to get element from list according to the condition

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
  resultlist = [[(u'Star', 68), (u'army', 68), (u'merged Into Party', 50)],
          [(u'dorlands Suffix', 60), (u'Human Development Index', 57), (u'champion', 45)],
          [(u'world Tournament Gold', 50), (u'worldwide', 50), (u'Continent', 50)],
          [(u'Human Development Index', 54), (u'Rank Single', 54), (u'champion', 54)],
          [(u'classification', 68), (u'reign', 62), (u'introduction Date', 57)],
          [(u'Human Development Index', 75), (u'humanity', 71), (u'XML Schema', 60)],
          [(u'load Limit', 60), (u'world Tournament Gold', 45), (u'champion', 45)],
          [(u'worldwide', 95), (u'world Tournament Gold', 86), (u'rid Id', 63)],
          [(u'distance Laps', 55), (u'department Code', 50), (u'kazakhstani Tenge', 50)],
          [(u'department Code', 72), (u'function Start Date', 57), (u'date Act', 54)]]
```

how to keep the element which the numerical value is >= 70.

for example, the result i expect will be look like as following:

```
finalresult= [[(u'Human Development Index', 75), (u'humanity', 71)],
              [(u'worldwide', 95), (u'world Tournament Gold', 86)],
              [(u'department Code', 72)]]

final_words=[u'Human Development Index',u'humanity',u'worldwide','world Tournament Gold',u'department Code']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested *list comprehension* with filter as:

```
 my_filtered_list = [[item for item in sub_list if item[1]>=70] for sub_list in resultlist]
 # value of my_filtered_list:
 # [[], [], [], [], [], [(u'Human Development Index', 75), (u'humanity', 71)], [], [(u'worldwide', 95), (u'world Tournament Gold', 86)], [], [(u'department Code', 72)]]
```

which will contain empty list in case there is no tuple present which satisfies the conditions. Looking at your output, since you do not need such values, filter such item using another *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> [sub_list for sub_list in my_filtered_list if sub_list]
[[(u'Human Development Index', 75), (u'humanity', 71)], [(u'worldwide', 95), (u'world Tournament Gold', 86)], [(u'department Code', 72)]]
```

Alternatively, you may also use `filter()` for the last part as:

```
>>> list(filter(None, my_filtered_list))
[[(u'Human Development Index', 75), (u'humanity', 71)], [(u'worldwide', 95), (u'world Tournament Gold', 86)], [(u'department Code', 72)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This works when I run it in Python IDLE:

```
filtered_list = [x for y in resultlist for x in y if x[1] >= 70]
```

I got the output:

```
[('Human Development Index', 75), ('humanity', 71), ('worldwide', 95), ('world Tournament Gold', 86), ('department Code', 72)]
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little more complex comprehension list for final words:

```
>>> # Final words
>>> [elem[0] for sublist in resultlist for elem in sublist if elem[1] >= 70]
>>> [u'Human Development Index', u'humanity', u'worldwide', u'world Tournament Gold', u'department Code']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resultlist = [[(u'Star', 68), (u'army', 68), (u'merged Into Party', 50)],
      [(u'dorlands Suffix', 60), (u'Human Development Index', 57), (u'champion', 45)],
      [(u'world Tournament Gold', 50), (u'worldwide', 50), (u'Continent', 50)],
      [(u'Human Development Index', 54), (u'Rank Single', 54), (u'champion', 54)],
      [(u'classification', 68), (u'reign', 62), (u'introduction Date', 57)],
      [(u'Human Development Index', 75), (u'humanity', 71), (u'XML Schema', 60)],
      [(u'load Limit', 60), (u'world Tournament Gold', 45), (u'champion', 45)],
      [(u'worldwide', 95), (u'world Tournament Gold', 86), (u'rid Id', 63)],
      [(u'distance Laps', 55), (u'department Code', 50), (u'kazakhstani Tenge', 50)],
      [(u'department Code', 72), (u'function Start Date', 57), (u'date Act', 54)]]

finalresult =[world for  elm in resultlist for world in elm if world[1]>=70]
finalwords =[world[0] for  elm in resultlist for world in elm if world[1]>=70]
print finalresult
```

Comment: How is your answer different from other answers available here?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy solution:

```
import numpy as np
resultlist  = np.array( resultlist )
finalresult = resultlist[ np.where( resultlist[ :, :, 1 ] >= u'70' ) ]
final_words = finalresult[ :, 0]
```

Output:

```
    [[u'Human Development Index' u'75']
     [u'humanity' u'71']
     [u'worldwide' u'95']
     [u'world Tournament Gold' u'86']
     [u'department Code' u'72']]
 ...
    [u'Human Development Index' u'humanity' u'worldwide'
 u'world Tournament Gold' u'department Code']
```